# msys2 doesn't starts at given location

Tags: msys2

I Tried

```
c:\app\msys2\msys2.exe -where "c:\project\project1"
```

and

```
c:\app\msys2\msys2.exe -c "cygptath -u 'c:\project\project1'"
```

and

```
c:\app\msys2\msys2.exe "bash -c cd $(cygptath -u 'c:\project\project1')"
```

But any such attempt starts a console that imediatly close.

Would any one know how to start msys2 in a given directory ?

Answer (score 0):

ok found the answer here:

https://gist.github.com/magthe/a60293fe395af7245a9e

c:\app\msys2\usr\bin\mintty.exe /bin/sh -lc 'cd "$(cygpath -w \"%P\"); exec bash'

this did the trick:

c:\app\msys2\usr\bin\mintty.exe /bin/sh -lc 'cd "/c/project/project1"; exec bash'